# How to get telegram bot user ID, outside of function Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I know how to get the user ID in the usual way:

```
async def start(message: types.Message):
   await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Here is your id {message.from_user.id}')
```

But the question is, is it possible to find out the id outside of the `async def start(message: types.Message)` function?